# How do I sever the connection between an account and my phone?

Tags: settings, sync, google, gallery, accounts

I have a Note 4, and recently I signed into a certain account so I could do something, nothing important, so I'd rather not say. Then, I removed it by going to  Settings> Accounts> (Accountname, or email or whatever) and I removed it from my device, so it doesn't show up there anymore, with sync, or anything. Gone.

But when I accessed my pictures from the Gallery, I now have a notification asking to sign into that account that I removed. I don't want anything to do with that account anymore, ever. Nothing at all. I can't figure out what still has my phone connected to that account, but whatever it is, I want it stopped.

I don't know if I have to sign back into that account, disable the syncing in Settings> Accounts> (Account name), or something.. which wouldn't make sense, because I removed it from the phone completely, before.. or what.

Anyway, I want to know how to sever whatever the connection is between my phone and that account, and what to do about it.

Comment: You could try using [SD maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) and clean up the corpses (trails of uninstalled account) and see if it helps. Let us know if it did, so that it can be made into an answer

Comment: Your account is not signed in currently, so anything is not syncing now

Comment: Thank you, beeshyams. So, I used SD maid, and so far, I'm not getting any sign in notifications. So far.